# nlargest index for entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, min

I have a few dataframes, all with the same format:

```
i |nameA |  A  | nameB |  B  | nameC |  C  | nameD |  D
-------------------------------------------------------
0 |  1   | 45  |   9   | 123 |  123  |  23 |   1   | 502
1 |  5   | 435 |   15  | 894 |  523  | 1.1 |   5   | 502
2 |  10  | 112 |   20  | 542 |  234  |  52 |   7   | 502
3 |  7   | 432 |   2   | 900 |  43   | 653 |   4   | 502            
4 |  8   | 854 |   6   | 234 |  853  |  50 |   3   | 502
5 |  9   | 231 |   80  | 435 |  95   |  56 |   9   | 502
```

I want to find the maximum & minimum n values across A, B, C, D, along with their indices so that I can find the 'names' which are 0~3digit integers.

from the above example dataframe, should I need max 4 values, I would like

```
(column, index, value, name):
(B, 3, 900, 2)
(B, 1, 894, 15)
(A, 4, 854, 8)
(C, 3, 653, 43)
```

and the min 4 should be:

```
(column, index, value, name):
(C, 1, 1.1, 523)
(C, 0, 23, 123)
(A, 0, 45, 1)
(C, 4, 50, 853)
```

not necessarily in this format.

the dataframe is not really sorted in any way, and names do not have any correlation with the values.

any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Edit: filled in the example dataframe and results.

Comment: can you provide a real complete (non truncated) example? and the matching output

Comment: welcome to SO, have a read of [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no provided example that is complete, here is one:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(100, 8)),
                   columns=['nameA', 'A', 'nameB', 'B', 'nameC', 'C', 'nameD', 'D'])
        .rename_axis('i')
        .reset_index()
     )
```

```
>>> df.head()
   i  nameA   A  nameB   B  nameC   C  nameD   D
0  0     44  47     64  67     67   9     83  21
1  1     36  87     70  88     88  12     58  65
2  2     39  87     46  88     81  37     25  77
3  3     72   9     20  80     69  79     47  64
4  4     82  99     88  49     29  19     19  14
```

Now you can reshape and `loc` the 4 `nlargest` values per group:

```
(df.set_index('i')
   .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns[1:].str.extract('(^name)?(.+)').fillna('value'),
                                      names=[None, 'columns']
                                     ), axis=1)
   .stack(level='columns')
   .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('columns', group_keys=False)['value'].nlargest(4).index]
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
     i columns  name  value
0    4       A    82     99
1   96       A    12     97
2   69       A    87     96
3   13       A    64     95
4   49       B    51     99
5   14       B     3     98
6   56       B    20     97
7   89       B    18     97
8    9       C    14     99
9   11       C    20     99
10  61       C    98     97
11  78       C    12     96
12  96       D    26     99
13  15       D     2     98
14  68       D    74     98
15  73       D    79     98
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer! I just needed the topmost n, so I changed the last bit to .nlargest(n, 'value'). works like wonders

Answer (score -1):

You can use `idxmax` and `idxmin` to get the index (col `i`) of the max and the min for each column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i':[0,1,2],'nameA':[1,5,10],'A':[45,435,112]})
df.set_index('i',inplace = True)
df.A.idxmax()
1
```